# Why is my table not showing up using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

This is my Javascript code.  I have been trying to debug this for a week and can not figure out what I have been doing wrong.  Please help me understand.  I am new at coding.

#### HTML File

```
<script type="text/javascript" onload="table()"> 
function table(puppyPics, pictureDesc, pictureDate){
        

// var puppyPics =[0,1,2,3,4];
//var pictureDesc = [0,1,2,3,4];
//var pictureDate = [0,1,2,3,4];

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var tbl= document.createElement("table");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

for (var i = 0; i < puppyPics.length; i++) {
    var row= document.createElement("tr");
    var cell= document.createElement("td");
    
    for (var j = 0; j < pictureDesc.length; j++) {
    document.createElement("tr");
    document.createElement("td");
    
    for (var x = 0; x < pictureDate.length; x++) {
    document.createElement("tr");
    document.createElement("td");
    
row.appendChild(cell);
}
tblBody.appendChild(row);
}
tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
body.appendChild(tbl);
tbl.setAttribute("border", "2")
    }


    }
</script>
```

#### External JS File

```
    var puppyPics = new Array();
    var pictureDesc = new Array();
    var pictureDate = new Array();
    
    puppyPics[0] = "AllTheKids.jpg";
    puppyPics[1] = "susie.jpg";
    puppyPics[2] = "princess.jpg";
    puppyPics[3] = "wicketAndCarlos.jpg";
    puppyPics[4] = "wicketAndGeorge.jpg";
    
    pictureDesc[0] = "This is all the new puppies together. They are so cute! I just want to hold them all.";
    pictureDesc[1] = "A friend held Susie up so that you can get a good look at her face. She looks just like her mom.";
    pictureDesc[2] = "This is Princess, she is the same color as her brother Wicket. She loves to just give kisses to everyone who holds her.";
    pictureDesc[3] = "Wicket is a very social puppy. He's not even afraid of Carlos who is my brother's dog.";
    pictureDesc[4] = "Finally, here is Wicket and George. I like how they are starting to play together. They will be running around the yard in no time";
    
    pictureDate[0] = "March 10, 2012";
    pictureDate[1] = "March 10, 2012";
    pictureDate[2] = "March 10, 2012";
    pictureDate[3] = "March 15, 2012";
    pictureDate[4] = "March 15, 2012";
```

Comment: could it be because you haven't actually called `table`?

Comment: Never use `document.write`. It doesn't work if you try it after the page is loaded. Use DOM manipulation.

Comment: The `table` function takes three arguments, then overwrites them immediately. What is the point of accepting them, then?

Comment: You use `[...]` within `table`, but you revert to `new Array(); [0]=; [1]=...` after the function definition. Why?

Comment: Learn to use objects. `[{url: "AllTheKids.jpg", desc: "This is all the new puppies together.", date: "March 10, 2012"}, {url: ...`

Comment: There is a stray `</script>` tag after the function

Comment: I was showing what was in my html document, and the external javascript document.  Sorry that I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @ChrisB hmm... could there be an unshown `<script>` later on before the rest of the code?

Comment: @JanDvorak Looks like it's smack dab in the middle of a JS file but the OP just stated that the code example is two documents in one

Comment: @JanDvorak what do you mean by the function overwriting the arguments immediately?

Comment: Also, sorry I am pretty new to using javascript

Comment: The function defines local variables with the same name as the method arguments. This means whatever was passed as those arguments is lost forever.

Comment: So instead of having the three variables inside the () of the function should I leave that blank?

Comment: @user3569729 Can you provide more informations about the errors you have? Also a full example on jsfiddle or similar sites would be best for the community to help you

Comment: I am trying to have the three different arrays be different data cells in the table and have the function loop through the different images/comments/dates so that each one matches up respectively.  When I test the page in my web browser the table doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Your original code should at least show a table with few numbers, and possibly wipe out everything else on the page. Probably you're not calling the function.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  This is driving me crazy.  I am working on editing my code now.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code, based on your code:

In the function "table", I leaved a comment almost at the end indicating the changed line.
Also, in several places, I replaced double quotes by quotes and quotes by doble quotes.
In the start of the function you can see a line with the statement "debugger". It is commented but if you uncomment it will be easy to debug the function with Firebug or another tool.

Sorry not explaining in more detail but it was a lot of changes.
If you have any question just ask.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>

  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Test</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    var puppyPics = new Array();
    var pictureDesc = new Array();
    var pictureDate = new Array();

    puppyPics[0] = "AllTheKids.jpg";
    puppyPics[1] = "susie.jpg";
    puppyPics[2] = "princess.jpg";
    puppyPics[3] = "wicketAndCarlos.jpg";
    puppyPics[4] = "wicketAndGeorge.jpg";

    pictureDesc[0] = "This is all the new puppies together. They are so cute! I just want to hold them all.";
    pictureDesc[1] = "A friend held Susie up so that you can get a good look at her face. She looks just like her mom.";
    pictureDesc[2] = "This is Princess, she is the same color as her brother Wicket. She loves to just give kisses to everyone who holds her.";
    pictureDesc[3] = "Wicket is a very social puppy. He's not even afraid of Carlos who is my brother's dog.";
    pictureDesc[4] = "Finally, here is Wicket and George. I like how they are starting to play together. They will be running around the yard in no time";

    pictureDate[0] = "March 10, 2012";
    pictureDate[1] = "March 10, 2012";
    pictureDate[2] = "March 10, 2012";
    pictureDate[3] = "March 15, 2012";
    pictureDate[4] = "March 15, 2012";
  //-->
  </script>

  <script src="TestScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head><body>

<br>
<input type="button" onclick="table(puppyPics, pictureDesc, pictureDate); return true;"  value="Create Table" />
<br>
</body></html>
```

**Javascript file "TestScript.js" referenced in the html as the following code **

```
function table(puppyPics, pictureDesc, pictureDate){
         //Uncomment the following line to force debugging with Firefox or with other tool
        // debugger;

        //Three following lines commented
    //var puppyPics =[0,1,2,3,4];
    //var pictureDesc = [0,1,2,3,4];
    //var pictureDate = [0,1,2,3,4];

    document.write('<table>');

    document.write('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < puppyPics.length; i++){
        document.write('<th class="puppyPics">' + puppyPics[i] + '</th>');
    }
    document.write('</tr>');
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < pictureDesc.length; i++){
        document.write('<th class="pictureDesc">' + pictureDesc[i] + '</th>');
    }
    document.write('</tr>');
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < pictureDate.length; i++){
        document.write('<th class="puppyPics">' + pictureDate[i] + '</th>');
    }
    document.write('</tr>');
    //The following line was changed in several places
    document.write('<tcaption>' + 'There are over ' + puppyPics.length + ' pictures on this site' + '</tcaption>'); //changed  
    document.write('</table>');
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help.  I tried your code, but I still can't seem to get the table to show up on the site.